# Find the intervals on which f is increasing or decreasing, find local max and min, find the intervals of concavity and the inflection points.

Tags: calculus

Given Interval is $[0,2\pi]$

$f(x) = \sin x + \cos x$

I did the derivative:

$f'(x)= \cos x - \sin x$

Then I found the critical points:

$\cos x - \sin x = 0$

$\frac{\cos x}{\cos x} - \frac{\sin x}{\cos x} =0$

$1-\tan x =0$

$x = \frac{\pi}{4} , \frac{5\pi}{4}$

I used a sign chart to find where the intervals increased and decreased:

Increases at $(0,\frac{\pi}{4}) , (\frac{5\pi}{4}, 2\pi)$

Decreases at $(\frac{\pi}{4} , \frac{5\pi}{4})$

So, Local max is  $(\frac{\pi}{4},\sqrt{2})$

And Local min is $(\frac{5\pi}{4},-\sqrt{2})$

I'm not sure what to do next in order to find the concavity and inflection points.

Comment: You found the first derivative, then similarly find the second derivative, and the interval(s) where $f''(x)$ is positive, zero or negative respectively.

Comment: Do you mean $-\sqrt{2}$ for the local minimum?

Comment: My bad, I forgot to type a $2$ next to the $\pi$ while editing your post. You might want to fix that.

Comment: @peterwhy So, I find the second derivative and solve for x = 0 then I look for interval(s) where it increases and decreases, and from that I get the concavity and inflection point right?

Comment: Hi, just saying off topic, I came across your post asking how to write a math problem in the body on the meta site. Then I saw the two questions you posted subsequently. I must say, your posts are pretty high quality, with the context and mathjax spot on. :)